# Matlab, adding colored fields behind grid

Tags: matlab-figure

I want to mark certain areas in my plot, which I have solved by using `rectangle`. Now the problem is that I would also like to have the grid on but this is covered by the rectangles. Is there a way to color different areas of the background or have the grid moved forward so that it is plotted above the rectangles?

My code looks like this:

```
rectangle('Position', [0 0.46 3*l+1 1.6], 'FaceColor', bg2);
rectangle('Position', [0 0.6 3*l+1 1.6], 'FaceColor', bg);
hold on
grid on
plot(Isr(:, 2), abs(Isr(:, 1)), 'r');
plot(Isx(:, 2), abs(Isx(:, 1)), 'b');
title('Current');
axis([0 3*l 0 1.6]);
legend(Legend);
xlabel('$k$');
ylabel('$I_F/I_{3\Phi}$');
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
l = 10;
x = linspace(0,l);

rectangle('Position', [0 0.46 l+1 1.6], 'FaceColor', 'm');
rectangle('Position', [0 0.6 l+1 1.6], 'FaceColor', 'g');
hold on
grid on
plot(x, sin(x), 'r');
plot(x, cos(x), 'b');
axis([0 l 0 1.6]);
legend('Sine', 'Cosine');
```

Comment: This code is unfortunately not runnable. Could you include the missing variable definitions? Also - which version of MATLAB are you using? In addition, could you maybe upload an illustration of what you are trying to achieve? This could really clear things up. For now you can try if [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96947-how-do-i-make-grid-lines-appear-on-top-of-my-image-but-below-my-text-objects-in-matlab-7-5-r2007b) helps...

Comment: I am using Matlab R2014b 64bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by modifying the `Layer` [property of your axes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html), which modifies the placement of grid lines and tick marks in relation to graphic objects:

```
l = 10;
x = linspace(0,l);

myax = axes;
rectangle('Position', [0 0.46 l+1 1.6], 'FaceColor', 'm');
rectangle('Position', [0 0.6 l+1 1.6], 'FaceColor', 'g');
hold on
grid on
plot(x, sin(x), 'r');
plot(x, cos(x), 'b');
axis([0 l 0 1.6]);
legend('Sine', 'Cosine');
myax.Layer = 'top';
```

Note that I also added an `axes` call to give me a handle to the axes. The same behavior can be accomplished without this by using [`gca`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html) with [`set`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html): `set(gca, 'Layer', 'top');`

[image: example]